# Was the reputation requirement for review tasks changed?

Tags: bug, reviewing

I can't access review tasks anymore:

[image: Review Queue dropdown says "There are no review queues available to you]

Is this a bug? Was the rep required for tasks changed? The tab works fine on Chess.SE

Comment: According to the [help center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), it should be available from 500 rep. So seems like a bug. They're loading fine for me. Have you tried again? Maybe it was a transient issue...

Comment: Check if you've been review banned.

Comment: Check the [review page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review) directly

Answer (score 6):

Ah, I've found what it is. Since I've used all of my available votes for today, I can't access the queues that I normally can, since they require being able to vote up/down if necessary.

[image: Unavailable review queues]

Answer (score 1):

You can also see this happen if you get banned from reviewing by a moderator. To see the reason for which you were banned, you must open the review icon in a new window, or manually navigate to `/review`.

There exists a request on Meta Stack Exchange to make the warning more clear in this case: [New review navigation does not tell review-banned users what happened or why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303584/new-review-navigation-does-not-tell-review-banned-users-what-happened-or-why)